# Gather discrete GPU temperature optimus

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I run Nvidia Optimus using Bumblebee. Is there a way to check discrete GPU temperature while running applications with optirun?

Comment: have you checked if nvidia-settings has this information? I'm not on Linux right now, so can't check.

Comment: Btw, maybe you'll need to run it with `optirun nvidia-settings`.

Comment: When I open it, only ¨Aplication Profiles¨ and ¨nvidia-settings Configuration¨ are shown which none displays the temperature. Running with optirun doesn´t change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command

```
optirun nvidia-smi
```

will print out the temperature and some other informations too.

UPDATE: The below comments suggest that in some unofficial packages of the nvidia-driver the `nvidia-smi` binary is not properly linked to `/usr/bin/`. If you have such problem that the `nvidia-smi` command is not found then look at `/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX/bin/nvidia-smi` for the binary, where XXX is your driver version number. (Or just do a do a `locate nvidia-smi` or a `find / -name nvidia-smi` to search for the file.) If you found the file just link it to `/usr/bin/` to be available as a simple command, so do something like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-331/bin/nvidia-smi /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
```

Comment: This command hasn't come with nvidia-319 package, so I don't have it installed and don't know how install.

Comment: @user236979 I'm not sure, because my optimus machine runs a different linux distro, but [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/nvidia-319/filelist) says that it is also in the Ubuntu package. Are you sure it is not there?

Comment: Yes. I've committed a mistake. My driver is the nvidia-331 one, which comes from an outside repository.

Comment: But do you have any idea about what are the good temperatures for normal gpu usage? I have a gt 750m

Comment: @user236979 Still I think it must be there, but maybe not linked to `/usr/bin`. So do a `locate nvidia-smi` or a `find / -name nvidia-smi` or just look in `/usr/lib/nvidia-331/bin/nvidia-smi`. I don't know the proper temperatures for that card.

Comment: You were right. I've found it at ¨/usr/lib/nvidia-331/bin/nvidia-smi¨. Thanks.

Comment: I also linked /usr/lib/nvidia-331/bin/nvidia-smi to /usr/bin: ``sudo ln /usr/lib/nvidia-331/bin/nvidia-smi /usr/bin/nvidia-smi``

Comment: @user236979 Good. I'm happy and added these infos to my answer.